# Open multiple screens for a list of commands

Tags: linux, shell, gnu-screen

I have a file in which each line contains a shell script as shown below

```
sh xyz.sh arg1 arg2
sh abc.sh arg1
sh klm.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

I want each command to be executed in a separate *screen*, Is there an easy way to do this rather than creating screen by the command

```
screen -S screen1
screen -S screen2
screen -S screen3
```

and executing each command from the file in corresponding screens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i counter=1     # set integer attribute
while read -r line; do
  screen -dmS screen$counter sh -c "$line"
  counter=counter+1
done < file
```